# Cannot read property loadChart of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, tradingview-api

I've been trying to implement TradingView but I always get this error when I try to load the data:

`vendor.js:782 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadChart' of undefined`

This error occurs on the "item.load(data)" line.

I've put a setTimeOut to delay the load, and it resolved for me like this:

```js
setTimeout(function (){
    item.load(data);
}, 500);
item.onChartReady(chartReadyHandler);
```

But for some users, it didn't, so I changed setTimeOut time to 1000ms, it resolved for some and not for others, so I always have to keep increasing the time for load, but for me, it delays to load, says "Invalid Symbol" and after 1s it loads correctly, but I can't just increase the timeout to 10000ms and get problems for users.

So, how can I just check to load on right time? A promise of the api or something?

I've tried to put it inside the chartReadyHandler, but it didn't worked, I've noticed it only enters on "onChartReady" after loading the data.

I've stuck on this for 2 days, please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with promises is the best way to solve your problem.

If load returns a promise try using subscribe, the code inside it will only execute after your request is finished.

```
item.load(data).subscribe((data) => {
    //rest of your code here
    item.onChartReady(chartReadyHandler)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't returned a promise, didn't worked :(

Comment: I've made it wrong. After correct it, your solution solved my problem. Thank you very much!